# Php delete function javascript/redirect

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, error-handling, sql-delete

Looked around at other answers but still unable to resolve my problem. Users are currently on crud/view.php. Clicking the 'Delete' button will bring up a JavaScript textbox asking "Are you sure" and taking them to crud/delete.php.

View.php session start:

```
<?php 

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['u_uid']))

    $uid = $_SESSION['u_id'];

    require_once('connect.php');

    $ReadSql = "SELECT * FROM `contact` WHERE users_id=$uid ORDER BY Name";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $ReadSql);

?>
```

This is my delete button on view.php

```
<td> <input type="button" onClick="deleteme(<?php echo $r['u_uid']; ?>)" name="Delete" value="Delete"></td>
```

Followed by the JavaScript message also on view.php

```
 <script language="Javascript">
 function deleteme(delid) {
 if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete?")){
window.location.href='delete.php?del_id='  
  }
 } 
 </script>
```

My delete.php is where I think the problem is

```
 <?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])){

  require_once('connect.php');

  $query = "DELETE from contact WHERE id=".$GET['del_id']." LIMIT 1"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  
  header('Location: crud/view.php');  

?>
```

Really appreciate the help. I'm a pleb.

Comment: What's your question basically?

Comment: AH. Clicking delete has the text box come up. But does not result in anything being deleted. Errors are coming up in /delete.php and I just think the syntax is out of knack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])) {

 require_once('connect.php');

 $query = "DELETE from contact WHERE id=".$_GET['u_uid']." LIMIT 1"; 
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  
 header('Location: view.php');  
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your delete button on view.php

```
<a class="btn" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');">delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missing `}` in your `delete.php`

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])){
    require_once('connect.php');

    $query = "DELETE from contact WHERE id=".$GET['del_id']." LIMIT 1"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  
    header('Location: crud/view.php');  
  }
?>
```

Comment: Fixed that a few minutes ago. Isn't the core problem :/